# inetmanet building error in omnet++

Tags: omnet++

I have added inetmanet package by downloading from the below link and importing the project in omnet++.
https://github.com/aarizaq/inetmanet-3.x

While trying to built the project, an error is thrown when it was processing the below step in the built process.
Creating shared library: ../out/gcc-debug/src/libINET.dll

The error thrown on the above step is given below:
g++.exe: error: CreateProcess: No such file or directory
make[1]: *** [Makefile:1558: ../out/gcc-debug/src/inet/linklayer/base/MACBase.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
make[1]: Leaving directory '/c/Users/Rashad/Downloads/inetmanet-3.x-inetmanet-3.5/src'
make: *** [Makefile:6: all] Error 2

Error is thrown while trying to execute any example in inetmanet and they are shown below:
Error: Cannot load library '../../../src//libINET.dll': The specified module could not be found
End.

Can anyone in this group explain me why this error is happening. Thanks in advance.

Note: omnet++ 5.1 is being used and INET examples are working fine.

Comment: does that file exist? It sounds like there's an earlier error that causes `MACBase.o` not to be generated. I'd recommend contacting the developers directly, because this appears to be a build issue.

Answer (score 1):

The issue was solved.
The folder "showcases" and "tutorials" were empty and in the git, they were being pulled from INET.
So in my case, I had to manually copy those 2 folders from INET and then paste into INETMANET and rebuild it.